# Akka stream retry repeated result

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm implementing a iterator to a HTTP resource, which I can recover a list of elements paged, I tried to do this with a plain `Iterator`, but it's a blocking implementation, and since I'm using `akka` it makes my dispatcher go a little crazy.

My will it's to implement the same iterator using `akka-stream`. The problem is I need bit different retry strategy.

The service returns a list of elements, identified by a `id`, and sometimes when I query for the next page, the service returns the same products on the current page.

My current algorithm is this.

```
var seenIds = Set.empty
var position = 0

def isProblematicPage(elements: Seq[Element]) Boolean = {
  val currentIds = elements.map(_.id)
  val intersection = seenIds & currentIds
  val hasOnlyNewIds = intersection.isEmpty
  if (hasOnlyNewIds) {
    seenIds = seenIds | currentIds
  }
  !hasOnlyNewIds
}

def incrementPage(): Unit = {
  position += 10
}

def doBackOff(attempt: Int): Unit = {
  // Backoff logic
}

@tailrec
def fetchPage(attempt: Int = 0): Iterator[Element] = {
  if (attempt > MaxRetries) {
    incrementPage()
    return Iterator.empty
  } 

  val eventualPage = service.retrievePage(position, position + 10)

  val page = Await.result(eventualPage, 5 minutes)

  if (isProblematicPage(page)) {
    doBackOff(attempt)
    fetchPage(attempt + 1)
  } else {
    incrementPage()
    page.iterator
  }
}
```

I'm doing the implementation using `akka-streams` but I can't figure out how to accumulate the pages and test for repetition using the streams structure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should the `return` line in `fetchPage` be `return Iterator.empty`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Flow.scan` stage was a good advice, but it lacked the feature to deal with futures, so I implemented it asynchronous version [`Flow.scanAsync`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#scanAsync) it's now available on akka `2.4.12`.

The current implementation is:

```
val service: WebService
val maxTries: Int
val backOff: FiniteDuration

def retry[T](zero: T, attempt: Int = 0)(f: => Future[T]): Future[T] = {
  f.recoverWith {
    case ex if attempt >= maxAttempts =>
      Future(zero)
    case ex =>
      akka.pattern.after(backOff, system.scheduler)(retry(zero, attempt + 1)(f))
  }
}

def isProblematicPage(lastPage: Seq[Element], currPage: Seq[Element]): Boolean = {
  val lastPageIds = lastPage.map(_.id).toSet
  val currPageIds = currPage.map(_.id).toSet
  val intersection = lastPageIds & currPageIds
  intersection.nonEmpty
}

def retrievePage(lastPage: Seq[Element], startIndex: Int): Future[Seq[Element]] = {
  retry(Seq.empty) {
    service.fetchPage(startIndex).map { currPage: Seq[Element] =>
      if (isProblematicPage(lastPage, currPage)) throw new ProblematicPageException(startIndex)
      else currPage
    }
  }
}


val pagesRange: Range = Range(0, maxItems, pageSize)

val scanAsyncFlow = Flow[Int].via(ScanAsync(Seq.empty)(retrievePage))

Source(pagesRange)
  .via(scanAsyncFlow)
  .mapConcat(identity)
  .runWith(Sink.seq)
```

Thanks Ramon for the advice :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Flow.scan` method is useful in such situations.

I would start your stream with a source of positions:

```
type Position = Int

//0,10,20,...
def positionIterator() : Iterator[Position] = Iterator from (0,10) 

val positionSource : Source[Position,_] = Source fromIterator positionIterator
```

This position source can then be directed to a `Flow.scan` which utilizes a function similar to your `fetchPage` (side note: you should avoid awaits as much as possible, there is a way to not have awaits in your code but that is outside the scope of your original question).  The new function needs to take in the "state" of already seen Elements:

```
def fetchPageWithState(service : Service)
                      (seenEls : Set[Element], position : Position) : Set[Elements] = {

  val maxRetries = 10

  val seenIds = seenEls map (_.id)

  @tailrec
  def readPosition(attempt : Int) : Seq[Elements] = {
    if(attempt > maxRetries)
      Iterator.empty
    else {
      val eventualPage : Seq[Element] = 
        Await.result(service.retrievePage(position, position + 10), 5 minutes)

      if(eventualPage.map(_.id).exists(seenIds.contains)) {
        doBackOff(attempt)
        readPosition(attempt + 1)
      }
      else 
        eventualPage            
    }
  }//end def readPosition

  seenEls ++ readPosition(0).toSet
}//end def fetchPageWithState
```

This can now be used within a `Flow`:

```
def fetchFlow(service : Service) : Flow[Position, Set[Element],_] = 
  Flow[Position].scan(Set.empty[Element])(fetchPageWithState(service))
```

The new Flow can be easily connected to your Position Source to create a Source of `Set[Element]`:

```
def elementsSource(service : Service) : Source[Set[Element], _] = 
  positionSource via fetchFlow(service)
```

Each new value from `elementsSource` will be an ever growing Set of unique Elements from fetched pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it was quite useful!
I'm trying to remove the `Await` from the code, and using your implementation and it doesn't support since the `seenElements` needed to be a `Future[Set[Element]]` so it would chain the scans instead of resolving.

I'll try `foldAsync` to see if it helps :)